# Converting a video file to a binary file and vice versa

Tags: flutter, video, binary

friends.

I am currently engaged in the process of converting a video file sourced from my assets into a binary file, as well as accomplishing the reverse operation, all within the Flutter framework using Visual Studio Code.

Would anyone be kind enough to share their knowledge on how to achieve this?
Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "converting to binary file"? your source video file is not a binary file? it is a text file or something?

Comment: i have a video file which is "video.mp4"
is it possible to convert it to txt file that consists of binary bits representing the video?
then the txt file will be used to retrieve the video file again

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? mp4 video file is a compressed binary file so why would you want to convert it to text file (whatever it means) and vice versa?

Comment: im trying to send and receive video on mobile application using free space optics (where light on represents the 1 bit and light off means 0 bit)
that's why I'm trying to reach the 0 and 1 bits